# Javascript leave ASCII characters and Currency Symbols

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I am trying to remove **non ASCII characters + non currency symbols** with this regex:

```
string.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E\p{Sc}]/g, '')
```

It turns out that the currency symbols are being removed :(

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) JavaScript's native regular expression object does not support Unicode categories (such as the `{Sc}` currency category in your regex pattern).

One thing you could consider is to use a third-party JavaScript library such as XRegExp (described [on this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xregexp.html)) to gain this functionality.

Comment: I could specificy the characters I want; lets say it's only: chars A-z + numbers 0-9 + space + symbols: € £ $ ! and #

Comment: Yes, that should work too. You could simply use `/[^a-z0-9 €£$!#]/ig` to target anything other than that set list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I’m a contributor to XRegExp — I wrote the scripts that generate the data for the Unicode plugin. Are you sure you have the Unicode plugin installed?

---

If you just need a single Unicode-aware regular expression, you may not want to pull in the entire XRegExp library + its Unicode plugin for just that. An alternative solution would be to use a build script that compiles the regular expression using [Regenerate](http://mths.be/regenerate) and [the Unicode data packages](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-7.0.0).

Here’s what that would look like in Node.js:

```
var regenerate = require('regenerate');

// Symbol, Currency (Sc)
var Sc = require('unicode-7.0.0/categories/Sc/code-points');

// Let’s create a set for the symbol we want to remove.
var set = regenerate() // Start with an empty set.
  .addRange(0x7F, 0x10FFFF) // Add all Unicode code points outside of the ASCII range.
  .add(Sc) // Add all `Sc` code points.
// Print the result.
console.log(set.toString());
```

Run `npm install regenerate unicode-7.0.0`, and then run this script as follows:

```
node generate-regular-expression.js
```

It will print the following output:

```
[\$\x7F-\uD7FF\uDC00-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF]
```

This can be used directly as part of a regular expression literal.

The main advantage of this approach is that you’ll never have to tweak the regular expression manually if you ever want to add or remove another character to the set. Instead, you can just change the script that generates it by adding or removing some symbols, then running it again. The code of the script is much more readable and maintainable than any regular expression, IMHO. Also, the output is as compact as possible: rather than introducing an entire library as a run-time dependency, you just insert a single regular expression literal.